# even when details view insert fails the application is sending an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, insert-into

I have an details view that is attached to a sql datasource. When a new workorder is inserted i am sending an email. Right now there is some issue with my program and the user is not able to insert the data from my application but the email still gets send assuming the data is inserted.

This is my Details View Inserted Method:

```
        protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
 if (successfull == true && Page.IsValid && e.AffectedRows ==1)
        {

            //TextBox TextBoxWorkOrderNumber = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox11"));
            TextBox TextBoxRequestor = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox3"));
            TextBox TextBoxDate = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1"));
            //TextBoxDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            TextBox TextBoxDepartment = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox4"));
            TextBox TextBoxCompletionDate = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox16"));
            TextBox TextBoxMachineDescription = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox5"));
            TextBox TextBoxMachineLocation = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox6"));
            TextBox TextBoxWorkRequired = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox7"));
            // DropDownList status = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
            TextBox TextBoxStatus = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox12"));
            TextBoxStatus.Text = "Open";






            DropDownList list = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1"));
            TextBox9.Text = list.SelectedValue;
            DropDownList lists = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
            TextBox14.Text = lists.SelectedValue;


            if (TextBoxRequestor.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxRequestor.Text = "Not Applicable";
            }
            if (TextBox14.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxDepartment.Text = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (TextBoxCompletionDate.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxCompletionDate.Text = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (TextBoxMachineDescription.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxMachineDescription.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

            if (TextBoxMachineLocation.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxMachineLocation.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

            if (TextBoxWorkRequired.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxWorkRequired.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

                if (TextBox9.Text == "Safety" && e.AffectedRows==1)
                {
                  {
                      bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
                      if (isLocal == true)
                      {
                          string id = TextBox13.Text.ToString();
                          System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                          mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("no_reply_workorder@.com");//who send
                          mm.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("abc@.com"));
                          //abc@abc.com
                          mm.Subject = "WorkOrders Type Safety";
                          mm.Body = "DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL" + "<br><br/>" + "WorkOrderNumber" 
        + ": &nbsp;" + "<a href=\"http://localhost:49695/SafetyReport.aspx?WorkOrderNum=" + TextBox13.Text + "\">"
         + TextBox13.Text + "</a>" + "<-Click on the Work Order Number For Report"
         + "<br><br/>" + "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" + 
        "<a href=\"http://localhost:49695/Safety.aspx?WorkOrderNum=" + 
        TextBox13.Text + "\">" + TextBox13.Text + "</a>" +
         "<-Click on this Work Order Number To Enter Data" + 
        "<br><br/>" + "Requestor" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxRequestor.Text +
         "<br><br/>" + "Date" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxDate.Text + 
        "<br><br/>" + "Department" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBox14.Text +
         "<br><br/>" + "Machine Description" + ":&nbsp;" + 
        TextBoxMachineDescription.Text + "<br><br/>" + 
        "Machine Location" + ":&nbsp;" + 
        TextBoxMachineLocation.Text + "<br><br/>" +
         "Work Required" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxWorkRequired.Text + "<br><br/>" 
                            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                            client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
                            client.Send(mm);
                            captureuseremail();
                       }
              }
    }
  }
```

i see an DetailsView1_Item Inserting how can i check if that is inserting into the sql database?? if the inserting is successful i like to set a boolean value to true and if true then perform the Details_View1 Inserted and send email else cancel the insert.

i am also using the insert button that comes with the details view. **please ask me for additional code if your confused and  i would more than happily provide it.**

please help :(

Added Additional code:

```
  INSERT INTO Master(Requestor, Date, Department, CompletionDate, MachineDescription, 
MachineLocation, [Type of Work Order], [Work Required], Status) 
VALUES (@Requestor, @Date, @Department, @CompletionDate, 
@MachineDescription, @MachineLocation, @Type_of_Work_Order, 
@Work_Required, @Status); SET @NewId = Scope_Identity()
```

i just have a  bool successfull; which i set to true at the end of Item_Inserting  method().

**when user clicks submit on the details view which is nothing but the command button insert then the code hits the item_inserting takes all the value**
Item_Inserting of the details view:

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

            //TextBox TextBoxWorkOrderNumber = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox11"));
            TextBox TextBoxRequestor = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox3"));
            TextBox TextBoxDate = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1"));
            //TextBoxDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            TextBox TextBoxDepartment = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox4"));
            TextBox TextBoxCompletionDate = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox16"));
            TextBox TextBoxMachineDescription = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox5"));
            TextBox TextBoxMachineLocation = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox6"));
            TextBox TextBoxWorkRequired = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox7"));
            // DropDownList status = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
            TextBox TextBoxStatus = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox12"));
            TextBoxStatus.Text = "Open";
            DropDownList list = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1"));
            TextBox9.Text = list.SelectedValue;
            DropDownList lists = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
            TextBox14.Text = lists.SelectedValue;

            if (TextBoxRequestor.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxRequestor.Text = "Not Applicable";
            }
            if (TextBox14.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxDepartment.Text = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (TextBoxCompletionDate.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxCompletionDate.Text = "Not Provided";
            }
            if (TextBoxMachineDescription.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxMachineDescription.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

            if (TextBoxMachineLocation.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxMachineLocation.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

            if (TextBoxWorkRequired.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                TextBoxWorkRequired.Text = "Not Provided";
            }

        successfull = true;
    }
    else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
          successfull = false;
        }


    }
```

This is Where the actual insert takes place, its my sqldatasource:

**all the values from the item_inserting are inserted here with an identity value **

```
protected void RequestorSource_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (successfull == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int newid = (int)e.Command.Parameters["@NewId"].Value;
                    TextBox13.Text = newid.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    successfull = false;
                }
               if (e.AffectedRows == 1 && successfull == true)
               {
                   successfull = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   successfull = false;
               }
            }
            else
            {
                successfull = false;
            }


        }
```

the issue is the email is still getting sent when i stop the program, how can i create a bad insert like i want it to fail similar what is happening to the user i am not able to recreate the issue for example i tried adding a new field in the insert statement but did not give it any values and the error it threw was you have more columns then values.

This is a picture of my details view:

[image]

**all of the .cs code at http://pastebin.com/6VC6FZK7 and the .aspx code at http://pastebin.com/QhjWNNt0 ** hope this helps out a bit.

Comment: Please show the code that is generating the insert and populating the `successfull` variable

Comment: I tried to format your code, but something's wrong or missing. After `if (TextBox9.Text == "Safety")` there are two `{` and on `mm.Body` the string `"Work Required"` is being concatenated to what?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete i have added the code you asked for buddy

Comment: @AndersonPimentel i have it fixed now, please help.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete yea but the important part of the question i asked was does the data get inserted into sql when it runs through item_inserted or item_inserting then i can set the successful to true.

Comment: If you post the c# code calling that insert I might be able to figure out more but just posting the raw SQL does not show me if your doing any error checking and handling. As posted in my answer below I believe that is your problem. Every time I ever insert/update/delete data from my DBs I always check to make sure it was good and no errors thrown before moving on and doing other tasks.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete i have added all the code you asked for above, please help

Comment: You  still seem to be missing code. From my understanding your users click the button and that fires `DetailsView1_ItemInserting` but I don't see that calling anything. I don't see any code where `successful` is declared. Please show all the c# code for the entire process.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete i have added the complete link for both the cs and .aspx buddy

Answer (score 0):

If you just setting the bool `successful` to true after the insert and have not done any error checking then it can fail and still send the email. I suggest either wrapping the `insert` code in a `TRY..CATCH..`and set the `succssful` state to false in the `catch` OR running a `IF...ELSE..` to check if the data was inserted correctly and setting the `successful` state there.

Comment: yea thats what im thinking